# How to loop through the resultset of query in the sql server user defined function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I want to apply loop in the resultset of query in the user defined function in sql server.
Here is the query:

```
select acc_no, balance from sav_acc_mcg where scheme_id ='001'
```

This query gives a no. of rows of acc_no. Now what i need to do is loop through that result and do some work with the result. But the problem is to loop through the resultset of the query. So help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(balance) as Total from sav_acc_mcg where scheme_id ='001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need CROSS APPLY. See @Quasnoi's blog (search "TVF"): http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/